how to determine profanity in sentence in Flutter? Cloud Natural Language API? Vertex AI?
I would like to implement a feature to determine how much profanity are contained in text string entered by user (if so, I give a warning to user).
Based on what I have searched, I think there could be two ways to achieve this.

Cloud Natural Language API
Vertex AI with Firebase

However, I have encountered a problem on each.
With Cloud Natural Language API, it seems like Cloud Natural Language API doesn't support Dart language. Or I just wasn't able to find documentations in Flutter.
With Vertex AI, it seems like giving me error whenever I access to response.text when passing sentence with profanity. Take a look at code snippet below.
try {
  // Initialize the Vertex AI service and the generative model
  // Specify a model that supports your use case
  // Gemini 1.5 models are versatile and can be used with all API capabilities
  final model =
  vertexai.FirebaseVertexAI.instance.generativeModel(model: 'gemini-1.5-flash');
  logger.i("initialized Vertex AI service successfully");
  // Provide a prompt that contains text
  final prompt = [vertexai.Content.text('Does this sentence include any bad language? answer me with Yes or No: ${partiesPostModel.body}')];
  logger.i("provided prompt successfully");
  // To generate text output, call generateContent with the text input
  final response = await model.generateContent(prompt);
  logger.i("generated content successfully");
  logger.i(response.text); // <- this is the place where giving me error when I passed profanity as part of prompt
} on GenerativeAIException catch (e) {
  logger.e("failed to generate content with Vertex AI service: ${e.message}");
} catch (e) {
  logger.e("failed to initialize Vertex AI service");
  logger.e("error: $e");
}

I wonder if asking Vertex AI to determine profanity in sentence is supposed to work or not since I have tested quite similar task at AI Studio and it works (showing me red warning sign where profanity included in the sentence to be requested though).
So my question is "what would be the way to achieve determining profanity in sentence out of those two possible approach?" otherwise, is there anything else I could use in Flutter?

For the Vertex AI solution you tried, it is likely triggering Gemini Safety filter block.
Vertex AI uses Gemini (1.5 in your case) as LLM model. When input and output content contains potential safety risks, Vertex AI may block the response based on your safety configuration (you can read more about Gemini safety guidance here). Thus, the response object might not contain the text field which normally contains the LLM generated response content. You can try following:

Debug/Analyze the response object to confirm that the safety block is triggered.
Here is a sample response from Gemini (might not match your specific model and API):
 "data": {
                "candidates": [
                    {
                        "index": 0,
                        "finishReason": "SAFETY",
                        "content": {
                            "role": "",
                            "parts": []
                        },
                "promptFeedback": {
                    "blockReason": "BLOCKED_REASON_UNSPECIFIED"
                }


Adjust the Model Safety filter configuration as documented here. Along with a proper prompt, you may get the system to response.


After all, Vertex AI is not specifically designed for profanity. Both Input and Output may be subject to safety blocking, it is not straightforward to get deterministic answer (if it returns at all). You can apply a heuristic approach that derive the content is profane if Gemini safety block is triggered. You need to carefully design your prompt, configure the safety configuration (lower the blocking level so the system),  Using trained classifiers to label each prompt with potential harms or adversarial signals, then Provide an error message or pre-scripted output.
Again, suggest reading the Gemini safety guidance carefully.
